# Verificar ocorrencia em REGEX para arquivos em php

Tags: php, regex

Em php, tenho que abrir um arquivo do sistema e verificar se após a ocorrência 10 de um char no caso "**;**" qual é o conteúdo logo após ele.

exemplo: `TPD;62384;P;;;;N;62308;N;;C;N;N;;F;02` qual seria o regex para este fim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar essa regex

```
(.*?;){10}(.*?);
```

**Explicação**
`(.*?;)` - Essa sequencia captura tudo que esta antes do caractere `;` de forma [lazy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html).
`{10}` - Esse é um quantificador, aqui ele expressa que a sequencia anterior deve ser capturada 10 vezes.

`(.*?);` - Então após a décima repetição da sequencia `.*?;` é colocado o segundo grupo de captura para dar *match* no conteúdo após a décima ocorrência de `;`.

Obs: É valido lembrar que o conteúdo que você quer capturar está no segundo grupo de captura dessa regex, não no primeiro.

[Você pode ver o funcionamento dessa regex aqui.](https://regex101.com/r/nxLEO7/1)

Comment: Entao se estiver na ocorrencia 1000, tenho que fazer 1000 vezes isso?

Comment: @ALE_ROM você teria que modificar o quantifier de 10 para 1000

Comment: Massa cara, Obrigado pela ajuda